# ops.object.mode_set() not working on 2.78

Tags: python, operator, error

When write ops.object.mode_set("EDIT") in console and press enter, it give me an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 187, in **call**
>       ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), C_dict, kw, C_exec, C_undo)
>   TypeError: Calling operator "bpy.ops.object.mode_set" error, expected a string enum in ('INVOKE_DEFAULT', 'INVOKE_REGION_WIN', 'INVOKE_REGION_CHANNELS', 'INVOKE_REGION_PREVIEW', 'INVOKE_AREA', 'INVOKE_SCREEN', 'EXEC_DEFAULT', 'EXEC_REGION_WIN', 'EXEC_REGION_CHANNELS', 'EXEC_REGION_PREVIEW', 'EXEC_AREA', 'EXEC_SCREEN')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write `mode=` as shown here: `bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')`